# Better Defining A Cicerone

Tags: discussion

In answering a question earlier today, I learned that Wikipedia does not have really any information on what a  "beer sommelier" is. When you search for Cicerone, beer sommelier appears in the "see also" section and the amount of information lacking is astounding.

I feel that in order to increase the excitement about beer and to make our community stronger we should take interest in things that affect our community.

Is editing and updating Wikipedia within the scope of the meta users?

Comment: Not sure why this is on the close queue—I think it's a good question, and appropriately placed in meta, precisely because it might be murky territory for the fact-based main site.

Comment: I actually started the close to vote. Someone made mention in chat that wiki editing would be a personal venture. However, if I were to reword so we got a well-rounded picture of a Cicerone, that would be appropriate for this site. Would still be outside of beer.se to edit wiki though.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, still. I personally don't mind the discussion happening here.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you want to improve wikipedia that's up to you really.  I don't think you need to ask for tacit permission (if that's what you're doing).

Comment: I am a horrible writer :(

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with Wikipedia isn't what we're here for, but SE is pretty great at establishing canonical references, and has lots of google juice. There's no reason we can't house that information here.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can always update the cicerone tag wiki. That would get the information out there and it would draw traffic to this site instead of to wikipedia.